# Strange javascript error when using Kongregates API

Tags: unity, javascript

In the hopes of finding a fellow unity3d developer also aiming for the Kongregate contest..

I've implemented the Kongregate API and can see that the game receives a call with my username and presents it ingame. I'm using `Application.ExternalCall("kongregate.stats.submit",type,amount);`

where `type` is a string "Best Score" and `amount` is an int (1000 or something).

This is the error I'm getting:

> You are trying to call recursively into the Flash Player which is not allowed. In most cases the JavaScript setTimeout function, can be used as a workaround.
>
> ```
> callASFunction:function(a,b){if(FABrid...tion, can be used as a workaround.");
> ```

I'm wondering, has anyone else had this error or am I somehow doing something stupid?

Thanks!

Comment: Any of this help? Google returns very little, this is about all I see. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1920/unity-communication-with-browser-problem

Comment: In fact you may want to try asking this same question over there and see if they can help you. http://answers.unity3d.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but I solved it by making sure the API was only initialized once. The problem with that is that if the person playing is a guest, it's impossible to get to know when the player logs in during play. I solved that with a work around, giving the player the possibility of manually saying when he/she has logged in. Not beautiful but works in war.